# Как узнать что выбрано в radiogroup в listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Начал изучать android. Возник вопрос, гугление не особо помогло.
Есть ListView наполненая некоторым количеством items. Каждый item состоит из TextView, RadioGroup, RadioButton соответственно. Собственно как получить выбранные юзером значения в RadioGroup по нажатию на кнопку. Количество item может быть произвольное. Никак не пойму как это сделать.

Так выглядит activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    tools:context=".QuestionsScrollActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_questions_scroll"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="none"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check answers"
        android:id="@+id/checkAnswers"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Собственно question.xml это item из которых состоит ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionNumberTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Test question"
        android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test answer"
                android:id="@+id/answerRadioButton1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test answer"
                android:id="@+id/answerRadioButton2"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test answer"
                android:id="@+id/answerRadioButton3"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test answer"
                android:id="@+id/answerRadioButton4"
                android:checked="false" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

и адаптер

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {
    public QuestionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Question> questions) {
        super(context, 0, questions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Question question = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.questionNumberTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
            viewHolder.questionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
            viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton1);
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton2);
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton3 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton3);
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton4 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton4);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        List<Answer> answerList = question.getAnswers();

        if (answerList != null) {
            viewHolder.questionNumberTextView.setText("Question # " + (position + 1));
            viewHolder.questionTextView.setText(question.getQuestion());
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton1.setText(answerList.get(0).getAnswer());
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton2.setText(answerList.get(1).getAnswer());
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton3.setText(answerList.get(2).getAnswer());
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton4.setText(answerList.get(3).getAnswer());

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView questionNumberTextView;
        TextView questionTextView;
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton1;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton2;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton3;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все очень просто - вешайте слушатель кликов в адаптере на `RadioGroup` и прописывайте колбэк (интерфейс обратного вызова) полученных данных, если их нужно передавать в активити.

Для идентификации переданных данных (в каком айтеме произошел клик) через колбэк передавайте так же текущее значение `position` из адаптера.

Если нужно получать данные из айтемов не в реальном времени (обрабатывать каждый клик отдельно), а ,например, по нажатии на какую то кнопку завершения выбора, то все еще проще- тогда колбэк не нужен, информация из слушателя собирается в какое то хранилище (коллекцию данных, моделей) и создается метод в адаптере, возвращающий эту коллекцию.
При клике на кнопку, активити обращается к этому методу и получает набор данных с результатами выбора.

Так же вышепомянутая коллекция данных по состояниям в `RadioGroup` понадобится для хранения текущего выбора и восстановления айтемов при скролле, так как айтемы периодически переиспользуются и если не сохранять состояние, то выбор будет утрачен.

Примерный код адаптера без колбэка может выглядеть так :

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {

    int [] checkedAnswers;

    public QuestionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Question> questions) {
        super(context, 0, questions);
        checkedAnswers  = new int[questions.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Question question = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.questionNumberTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
            viewHolder.questionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
            viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

            //запоминаем какой элемент выбран в определенной позиции
            viewHolder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    switch (checkedId) {
                        case -1: // ничего не выбрано
                            checkedAnswers[position] = -1;
                            break;
                        case R.id.answerRadioButton1:
                            checkedAnswers[position] = 0;
                            break;
                        case R.id.answerRadioButton2:
                            checkedAnswers[position] = 1;
                            break;
                        case R.id.answerRadioButton3:
                            checkedAnswers[position] = 2;
                            break;
                        case R.id.answerRadioButton4:
                            checkedAnswers[position] = 3;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton1);
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton2);
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton3 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton3);
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton4 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRadioButton4);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        List<Answer> answerList = question.getAnswers();

        if (answerList != null) {
            viewHolder.questionNumberTextView.setText("Question # " + (position + 1));
            viewHolder.questionTextView.setText(question.getQuestion());
            //восстанаваливаем выбор в RadioGroup
            if (checkedAnswers[position] == -1) viewHolder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
              else viewHolder.radioGroup.check(((RadioButton)viewHolder.radioGroup.getChildAt(checkedAnswers[position])).getId());

            viewHolder.answerRadioButton1.setText(answerList.get(0).getAnswer());
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton2.setText(answerList.get(1).getAnswer());
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton3.setText(answerList.get(2).getAnswer());
            viewHolder.answerRadioButton4.setText(answerList.get(3).getAnswer());

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    //метод возвращает массив с результатами выбора в списке
    public int[] getCheckedAnswers (){
        return checkedAnswers;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView questionNumberTextView;
        TextView questionTextView;
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton1;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton2;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton3;
        RadioButton answerRadioButton4;
    }
}
```

Здесь мы при клике в `RadioGroup` считываем, на какой из `RadioButton` кликнул пользователь и сохраняем его выбор, далее, при формировании айтема восстанавливаем выбор пользователя, чтобы избежать потери введенных данных из-за переиспользования элементов списка.
метод `getCheckedAnswers()` возвращает массив значений, где позиция в массиве будет соответствовать позиции в списке, значения следующие:

- -1 - ничего не выбрано
- 0 - выбран первый пункт в RadioGroup
- 1 - выбран второй пункт
- 2 - выбран третий пункт
- 3 - выбран четвертый пункт

обращаться из активити (например в обработчике клика по кнопке checkAnswers) следующим образом:

```
int[] checkedAnswers = adapter.getCheckedAnswers();
```

PS: этот код мне негде протестировать, поэтому он является скорее шаблоном для демонстрации решения, чем готовым решением для копипаста.

Comment: Если не трудно киньте ссылкой на пример